# how to make sure that SSIS uses SSL to transfer data to Azure Database

Tags: sql-server, azure, ssl, ssis

In my local computer, I am running SSIS package to transfer data to Azure DB in every hour. How can I make sure that my SSIS uses SSL to transfer the data. I went through various online tutorials and SO posts but didn't find how to confirm that SSL is being used. MS Azure tutorials recommends to use `Encrypt=True` and `TrustServerCertificate=False` in connection string.

My connection string for OLe DB destitaion (Azure) is

```
Data Source=tcp:AAAAAA.database.windows.net,1433; User ID=dbadmin@AAAAAA;    
Initial Catalog=testdb; Persist Security Info=True; Encrypt=True;     
TrustServerCertificate=False; Application Name=SSIS-Package-BBBBB;
```

How do I understand that SSL is being used? Do I have to install any certificate in my local computer?

Comment: In the referenced duplicate, Tony Petrossian - who works at MS, indicates "All connections to Azure SQL Database are encrypted by default and unencrypted connections are rejected"

Comment: in SSIS  OLE DB connection, even though I provide Encrypt = FALSE and TrustServerCertificate = TRUE, the data transfers without having any error. Why the connection is not rejected by Azure?

Comment: Because you are trusting the server cert, I believe that's using the server cert to encrypt the data (checking with a security person to verify). This [Azure article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-security/) indicates that trusting the server cert is not suggested

Answer (score 1):

SSL is being used when `Encrypt=True`. From: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

When true, SQL Server uses SSL encryption for all data sent between the client and server if the server has a certificate installed. Recognized values are true, false, yes, and no. For more information, see Connection String Syntax.

Beginning in .NET Framework 4.5, when TrustServerCertificate is false and Encrypt is true, the server name (or IP address) in a SQL Server SSL certificate must exactly match the server name (or IP address) specified in the connection string. Otherwise, the connection attempt will fail. For information about support for certificates whose subject starts with a wildcard character (*), see Accepted wildcards used by server certificates for server authentication.

If you would like to double check, you can observe the network traffic with Wireshark.